# Bookshelf in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I am writing an Android app that [shows books on a shelf](http://onsoftware.en.softonic.com/gooreader-a-better-interface-for-google-books) and I'm using buttons with an image to display them.

My problem is that when I click the image it should *zoom* closer, but the background of the bookshelf should still be visible. I'm not sure how to do this, can someone help?

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I need an effect similar to lightbox when I click that image.Once again thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use coverflow in github.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

And use anim for zoom in image and zoom out,slide in and out etc.,

May be this might help you